# Parallel process interest in C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

In web api controller:
I am a newer in **parallel** and **Async&Task** programming. Need someone help me code review.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoWork()
{
    List<string> listTask = await Helper.GetBlockBlock();
    userIds = listTask;
    this.ParallelTaskWork();//step 1,must be finished,but I an not sure when..
    await this.Service.GetAllClientInterestInfoList();//executing after step 1 
    return this.Ok();
}
public async void ParallelTaskWork()
{
    Task[] taskList = this.TaskMaker(totalNum);
}
public Task[] TaskMaker(int threadNum)
{
    Task[] taskList = new Task[threadNum];
    Parallel.For(0, taskList.Length, i => taskList[i] = new Task(this.ProcessDealTask));
    Parallel.ForEach(taskList, t => t.Start());
    return taskList;
}
private void ProcessDealTask()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++)
    {
        List<string> users = this.GetPartitionOfList(userIds, i, totalNum);
        Task task = this.ParallelDealUserList(users);
        task.Wait();
    }
}
private List<T> GetPartitionOfList<T>(List<T> userList, int index, int total)
{
    int section = (userList.Count / total) + 1;
    int end = (index + 1) * section > userList.Count ? userList.Count - index * section : section;
    if (end < 0) end = 0;
        int start = index * section < userList.Count ? index * section : userList.Count - 1;
    if (start < 0) start = 0;
        return userList.GetRange(start, end);
}
private async Task ParallelDealUserList(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(list, async (id, loopState) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await GrainClient.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IUser>(id.ToGuid()).DoProcessInterestAsync(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }));
}
```

Any performance problem? The method **ParallelDealUserList** I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall
somebody said

> there is a disadvantage to use Task.Run in a loop- With
>   Parallel.ForEach, there is a Partitioner which gets created to avoid
>   making more tasks than necessary

and  The method **TaskMaker**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988630/parallel-for-w-action-that-creates-different-tasks-c-sharp

Comment: What kind of process you are running? ASP.NET?

Comment: @DmitryNogin .net platform

Comment: OK, but is it ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC, or WPF, or WinForms, or Console (Service)? What kind of Task Scheduler are you using?

Comment: @DmitryNogin hi, we use web api controller

Answer (score 4):

First thing is that you should limit the degree of parallelism, to ex: 4 threads

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    listOfWebpages,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    webpage => { Download(webpage); }
);
```

Without this, you are going to DDoS your service or resource you are using.

---

You seem to be using Project Orleans and AFAIK a grain should be a single threaded container. You should be able to do just:

```
private void ParallelDealUserList(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
        GrainClient
            .GrainFactory
            .GetGrain<IUser>(item.id.ToGuid())
            .DoProcessInterestAsync(true);
}
```

---

I am not all that familiar with Project Orleans. Most likely this can be used, but I would use microservices (aka SOA2) instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is really dangerous to fork background threads in ASP.NET. Task Scheduler immediately gets crazy, which degrades performance significantly.

There is a way though: `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

> QBWI schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of
>   any request. This differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that
>   ASP.NET automatically keeps track of how many work items registered
>   through this API are currently running, and the ASP.NET runtime will
>   try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished
>   executing.

Please have a look at [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: May you explain more detail. plz. =)

Comment: @xian-yu Sure :) See detailed problem explanation - [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). Potential solution is explained in [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).